# Autopopulating list versus list

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have been using spring autopopulating list to create forms on the fly but lately i have to use a framework that doesn't allow the use of autopopulating list. So I was thinking can i use normal java arraylist to achieve the same results. Also if can use arraylist  then what are pros and cons of using one over the other. Please can anyone tell me that.

Comment: Do you understand what `AutoPopulatingList` does that `ArrayList` does not?

Comment: i don't know the differences , that exactly why i asked the question.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/AutoPopulatingList.html) is pretty clear. `AutoPopulatingList` will create elements in the `get()` method if they don't already exist.

Comment: I'm very curious which framework wouldn't allow it. Would it call the police if you did?

Comment: Its just a company made framework where some sort of mapping takes place and the mapping function only takes native java elements and we aren't suppose to tinker with the framework code.